# Python user input as regular expression, how to do it correctly?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, user-input, string-literals

I'm using Python 3. In my application, the use can input a regular expression string directly and the application will use it to match some strings. For example the user can type `\t+`. However I can't make it work as I can't correctly convert it to a correct regular expression. I've tried and below is my code.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.compile(re.escape("\t+")).findall("  ")
[]
```

However when I change the regex string to `\t`, it will work.

```
>>> re.compile(re.escape("\t")).findall("   ")
['\t']
```

Note the parameter to `findall` IS a tab character. I don't know why it seems not correctly displayed in Stackoverflow.

Anyone can point me the right direction to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Compile user input

I assume that the user input is a string, wherever it comes from your system:

```
user_input = input("Input regex:")  # check console, it is expecting your input
print("User typed: '{}'. Input type: {}.".format(user_input, type(user_input)))
```

This means that you need to transform it to a regex, and that is what the `re.compile` is for. If you use `re.compile` and you don't provide a valid `str` to be converted to a regex, it will **throw an error**.

Therefore, you can create a function to **check if the input is valid or not**. You used the `re.escape`, so I added a flag to the function to use `re.escape` or not.

```
def is_valid_regex(regex_from_user: str, escape: bool) -> bool:
    try:
        if escape: re.compile(re.escape(regex_from_user))
        else: re.compile(regex_from_user)
        is_valid = True
    except re.error:
        is_valid = False
    return is_valid

print("If you don't use re.escape, the input is valid: {}.".format(is_valid_regex(user_input, escape=False)))
print("If you do use re.escape, the input is valid: {}.".format(is_valid_regex(user_input, escape=True)))
```

If your user input is: `\t+`, you will get:

```
>> If you don't use re.escape, the input is valid: True.
>> If you do use re.escape, the input is valid: True.
```

However, if your user input is: `[\t+`, you will get:

```
>> If you don't use re.escape, the input is valid: False.
>> If you do use re.escape, the input is valid: True.
```

Notice that it was indeed an invalid regex, however, by using `re.escape` your regex becomes valid. That is because `re.escape` *escapes* all your special characters, treating them as literal characters. So in the case that you have `\t+`, if you use `re.escape` you will be looking for a sequence of characters:  `\`, `t`, `+` and not for a `tab character`.

## Checking your lookup string

Take the string you want to look into.
For example, here is a string where the character between quotes is supposed to be a tab:

```
string_to_look_in = 'This is a string with a "  " tab character.'
```

You can manually check for tabs by using the `repr` function.

```
print(string_to_look_in)
print(repr(string_to_look_in))
```

```
>> This is a string with a "    " tab character.
>> 'This is a string with a "\t" tab character.'
```

Notice that by using `repr` the `\t` representation of the tab character gets displayed.

## Test script

Here is a script for you to try all these things:

```
import re

string_to_look_in = 'This is a string with a "  " tab character.'
print("String to look into:", string_to_look_in)
print("String to look into:", repr(string_to_look_in), "\n")

user_input = input("Input regex:")  # check console, it is expecting your input

print("\nUser typed: '{}'. Input type: {}.".format(user_input, type(user_input)))


def is_valid_regex(regex_from_user: str, escape: bool) -> bool:
    try:
        if escape: re.compile(re.escape(regex_from_user))
        else: re.compile(regex_from_user)
        is_valid = True
    except re.error:
        is_valid = False
    return is_valid

print("\nIf you don't use re.escape, the input is valid: {}.".format(is_valid_regex(user_input, escape=False)))
print("If you do use re.escape, the input is valid: {}.".format(is_valid_regex(user_input, escape=True)))

if is_valid_regex(user_input, escape=False):
    regex = re.compile(user_input)
    print("\nRegex compiled as '{}' with type {}.".format(repr(regex), type(regex)))

    matches = regex. findall(string_to_look_in)
    print('Mathces found:', matches)

else:
    print('\nThe regex was not valid, so no matches.')
```

Answer (score 1):

The result of `re.escape("\t+")` is `'\\\t\\+'`. Note that the + sign is escaped with a backslash and is not a special character anymore. It does not mean "one or more tabs."

Comment: So in my case how can I use it correctly? The regex string could be very complex as it's provided by the user.

Comment: If you want to avoid any unexpected special characters (if you want a + to mean a +, not a "repeat"), then yes.

Answer (score 1):

A literal `\t+` from an external source is not the same thing as the literal string `"\t+"`. What does `print("\t+")` output? What about `print(r"\t+")`? The latter is equivalent to accepting that literal string as input to be used as a regex. The former is not. However, for this specific situation the distinction does not matter since a literal tab character should behave exactly the same as `\t` in a regex. Ponder the following examples from an Ipython session:

```
In [24]: re.compile('\t+').findall('^I')
Out[24]: ['\t']

In [25]: re.compile('\t+').findall("\t")
Out[25]: ['\t']

In [26]: re.compile(r'\t+').findall('^I')
Out[26]: ['\t']

In [27]: re.compile(r'\t+').findall("\t")
Out[27]: ['\t']

In [28]: re.compile(r'\t+').findall(r"\t")
Out[28]: []
```

I can only conclude your first example, the one which didn't produce the expected output, did not have a literal tab in the quoted string.

Also, `re.escape()` is not appropriate for this situation. Its purpose is to ensure that a string from an untrusted source is treated literally rather than a regex so that it can safely be used as a literal string to be matched.